# yup validation schema conditional validation on object

Tags: validation, next.js, schema, yup

```
    import * as Yup from "yup";
import * as consts from "../consts-for-yup";

export const legalNoFurtherActionValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  NrwDecision: Yup.object().shape({
    Id: consts.NumberRequired(),
    Name: consts.StringNotRequired,
  }),
  NoFurtherAction: Yup.object().when("NrwDecision.Id", {
    is: 6,
    then: Yup.object().shape({
      DecisionMade: consts.DateRequired,
      Comments: consts.StringNotRequired,
    }),
    otherwise: Yup.object().nullable(),
  }),

  FixedPenaltyNotice: Yup.object().when("NrwDecision.Id", {
    is: 5,
    then: Yup.object().shape({
      DecisionMade: consts.DateRequired,
      Comments: consts.StringNotRequired,
    }),
    otherwise: Yup.object().nullable(),
  }),
  Id: consts.NumberNotRequired,
  ObjectState: consts.NumberNotRequired,
});
```

So basicllly what I want to achive here when NrwDecision.Id is 6 i want this validation look one way otherwise I want that to be and object and It can nullable as I know It wont have any data>
I am trying to reuse the same schema for couple diffrnet forms

The issue I am having is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgqx3.png)